# Extract data from SIMFIT or get equation of fit, after running data fitting program (mmfit)

Tags: statistics, math-software, data-analysis

I am a biochemist using the statistical program SIMFIT with the curve fitting program called mmfit (mikaelis menten curve fitting).

From my raw data (which is 10 concentrations and 3 replicates measured at each concentration) I get a nice curve which fits my data points. **However**, I would like to extract the data which SIMFIT uses to plot this fit-curve to my data points - so that I can use a different program (LaTex) to plot my fitting-curve with my measured data points.

How can I extract data from SIMFIT which equals the entire fit-cruve, not just the fit which matches the exact datapoint that I gave the program? Or get the equation from the fit out, so that I can write it in a different program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Advanced] button and choose to save the data to files.
Contact the author (w.g.bardsley) for more details